# I am looking for SQL code that will delete duplicates where a duplicate is defined as the equality of two specific fields

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a MySql database with 5 fields.  There are two critical fields, Cfield1 and CField2.  If for any two entries the values of Cfield1 are identical AND the values of Cfield2 are also identical, then I want to delete one of the two -- it does not matter which.

If there are three that are identical I want only 1 to remain and delete the rest.

I presume that the first thing to do is sort the db on Cfield1 and then Cfield2, but I am not sure what the rest of the coding should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you have another column -- say `col3` -- that can differentiate the duplicate rows.  Then you can do:

```
delete t
    from t t join
         (select cfield1, cfield2, min(col3) as min_col3
          from t
          group by cfield1, cfield2
         ) tt
         using (cfield1, cfield2)
    where t.col3 > tt.min_col3;
```

If you don't have such a column, then I might suggest creating a new table.  The following uses a feature of MySQL that a pretty much totally discourage using, but it should do what you want:

```
create table temp_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    group by col1, col2;

truncate table t;  -- be very careful here, copy the data somewhere else first!

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use count (*) and group by together:

```
select count (*),DuplicateField from table
group by  DuplicateField
having count (*)>1
```

As a result ,You will get records .
Or if you want delete I can tell you with an example of mine:

```
select 
    'RepetedRows',
    SA.Saleref,
    MIN(CAST(SA.SaleAdditionID  as varchar(100)) ),
    'DELETE sms.tblsaleadditions    WHERE SaleAdditionID = ''' + MIN(CAST(SA.SaleAdditionID as varchar(100)) ) + ''''
    --select * 
from 
    sms.tblsaleadditions    SA
inner join (
    select
        saleref,
        additionref,
        count(*)    N,
        SUM(AdditionAmount) nn
    from 
        sms.tblsaleadditions
    group by 
        saleref,
        additionref
    having count(*) > 1
    ) V ON SA.saleref = V.Saleref and SA.additionref = V.additionref 
group by 
    SA.Saleref
```

Now  you can copy all delete statements and run them.

Answer (score 0):

What would this be in MySQL queries? We have this requirement, but the existing database is MySQL.